# What is the real size of mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, css, responsive-design

I want to write css to devices. In the devtools `Galaxy S5` for example say the size is 360x640.

[image]

But according to [screensiz website](http://screensiz.es/galaxy-s) `Galaxy S5` is 480x800.

[image]
Which of them is correct?

Comment: Incidentally you have highlighted `Galaxy S` not `Galaxy S5` which is here [http://screensiz.es/galaxy-s5](http://screensiz.es/galaxy-s5) and shown as 1080x1920 not 480x800.

Comment: still. why devtools say incorrect widthxheight?

Answer (score 1):

A mobile phone's screen size is not necessarily the same as it's web browser viewport size. You should design your website based on the browser viewport and not on the actual pixel size.

You can read some more about this, as well as find the viewport size for many devices [here](https://mediag.com/blog/popular-screen-resolutions-designing-for-all/).

Comment: but where devtools say Galaxy S5 size is 360x640?